# Cannot read property 'error' of undefined in map.addControl in leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

First I write a code to create a toolbar with *leaflet.draw*

```
var drawPluginOptions = {
    position: 'topright',
    draw: {
        polyline: false,
        circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
        rectangle: false,
        marker: false,
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
            showArea: true,
            drawError: {
                color: '#ffc107', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
            },
            shapeOptions: {
                color: '#057d50'
            },
        },

    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
        remove: true,
        edit: true,
    }
};

var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawPluginOptions);
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

After that, I localized the messages and titles with *L.drawLocal*.
I need to recreate the map but it cause error *Cannot read property 'error' of undefined*
I want to know how use Both of them without any problem

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? You can use this JSFiddle as a starter: https://jsfiddle.net/6kwqLpmc/2/  (it contains the code you've posted, but does not produce any errors)

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the reason for this problem is because of  **L.drawLocal**, not **map.addControl**.

First I checked the error code and "*Cannot read property 'error' of undefined*" message was related to polyline error. So, I added the errors that I did not need to localize like this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53401594/2543986

After that, I changed position of **L.drawLocal** to *top* of **map.addControl**